# method query() from simpleJdbcTemplate is not returning values

Tags: java, templates, jdbc, methods

I have my class that is something like this:

```
public class DBConection extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements ElectionsDao{
public List<String> getDates(){
        try{
            String sql = "SELECT electiondate FROM electiondate";
            List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
            dates = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql,  
                    ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(String.class));

            System.out.println(dates.size());
            System.out.println(dates.get(0));

            return dates;
        }catch(DataAccessException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the values from the SQL statement and then add them as String objects to a List but when I run my project it returns the number of values but all in blank. Does anybody know why? I have my configuration file and everything. I think that it has to be a problem defining the `query()`. I'm using the Spring framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out how to do it.

Here's how I did it:

```
public class DBConection extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements ElectionsDao{
    public List<String> getDates(){
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            dates = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT electiondate FROM electiondate";, new StringRowMapper());
        } catch (DataAccessException ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return dates;
    }

    protected static final class StringRowMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<String> {
        public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int line) throws SQLException {
            String string = new String(rs.getString("electiondate"));
            return string;
        }
    }
}
```

I had to do a "StringRowMapper" inner class for this to work.

Hope it helps you!